# How can I make this old JavaScript/ASP Classic code (clean) unobtrusive, using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I'm a working on a old system that is using ASP Classic scripting.

In the ASP Classic file I have this code fragment which renders a part of a table:

```
<td nowrap align="center">
  <%if iBidCount > 0 then %>
    <a class="number-of-bids" onClick="showBidHistory(<% = oRSResults("ListedPlatesId") %>, this);" title="Click to show bid history"><%= iBidCount %></a>
  <% else %><span class="no-bids">0</span>
  <%end if%>
</td>
```

The JavaScript I have for onClick event is as follows:

```
function fetchBidHistory (pListedPlatesId) {
        var d = new Date();
        var t = d.getTime();

        $.get('/auction/includes/new-bidhistory.asp?lplateid=' + pListedPlatesId + "&xx=" + t, 
        function(data){
            $('#BidHistory').html(data).animate({opacity:1.0}, 400);
        }); 
}

function showBidHistory(pListedPlatesId, pObj) {
    var lyrBidHistory = $('#BidHistory');
    //Populate the DIV
    fetchBidHistory (pListedPlatesId);       
}
```

As you can see I have managed to implement some JQuery into it. I am aiming to make the JavaScript unobtrusive as possible. Also I'm having trouble getting `DIV#BidHistory` to disappear once it is visible???

Is there a way to get this done? Any Ideas?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your JavaScript to be unobtrusive, one of the first steps is to remove event handlers from html and replace them with event listeners in your javascript file.

Example:

```
 <a class="number-of-bids" onClick="showBidHistory();">Old Link</a>
```

Becomes:

```
  <a class="number-of-bids" id="bidHistoryLink">New Link</a>
```

With an extra line of code in your JavaScript similar to:

```
$('#bidHistoryLink').click(function() {
alert('your bid history is:' bidHistory);
});
```

Doing this allows you to be much more dynamic in how you structure and reorganize the site. Making changes across the website especially become a lot easier to manage.